# how to generate software interrupt by some method other than using assembly instruction

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, x86, microprocessors

Can someone please let me know if there is any other way of generating software interrupts other than using the assembly instruction for interrupt provided by the processor instruction set ? For eg http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_%28x86_instruction%29 states that

```
INT X
```

can be used for generating software interrupt. I would like to know if there is any other way of generating software interrupts that is used in practice (say if the processor instruction set doesn't have any such instruction) ? Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why would a CPU bother to implement software interrupts if there were no instruction to trigger them?

Comment: Its not the CPU that will bother to implement the sw interrupt. Suppose i have to develop a application that requires software interrupts and the underlying cpu doesn't have an assembly instruction to support the same, is there any other way i can implement the software interrupt ?

Comment: @CL. : I thought of following possible solution to this problem. Whenever i want to generate s/w interrupt in my program, i can update the program counter register to point to a routine that will handle the various interrupts. In that routine, i can do the usual stuff to do context saving, running corresponding ISR etc. I would like to know your view, if this solution would serve the same purpose as would have been served had i used some assembly instruction like INT X.

Comment: The CPU will not allow the application to execute code in pages that are marked as belonging to the kernel.

Comment: @CL. : i couldn't get you when you say that "...to execute code in pages that are marked as belonging to the kernel" . Nowhere i am asking cpu to execute a code in pages belonging to kernel. I am just writing a routine to handle the interrupts (which can reside anywhere in memory) and passing the address of that routine to program counter register.

Comment: Interrupt handlers typically are part of the kernel. Jumping to your own code is just a function call. What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: @CL. : yeah, jumping to own code will be just a function call, but then fn call is also changing the execution sequence (to run ISR) similar to execution sequence changed by instruction INT X (to run ISR). i am working on a processor which doesn't have any such assembly instruction.

Comment: Then don't keep the processor model a secret. And what, specifically, do you need that isn't done by a function call?